# how can I parse/embedd my atom feed in my webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, atom-feed

I have created a test page called syndication.php where mysql data is being created in an Atom feed like this:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"> 
        <title>Fishing Reports</title> 
        <subtitle>The latest reports from apporan.com</subtitle>
        <link href="http://www.apporan.com/reports" rel="self"/> 
        <updated><?php echo date3339(); ?></updated>
        <author> 
            <name>Smithers</name>
            <email>smithers@fishinhole.com</email>
        </author>
        <id>tag:apporan.com,2015:http://www.apporan.com/syndication.php</id> 


        <?php
            $i = 0;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
              {
              if ($i > 0) {
                echo "</entry>";
              }
              $articleDate = $row['posted'];
              $articleDateRfc3339 = date3339(strtotime($articleDate));
              echo "<entry>";
              echo "<title>";
              echo $row['title'];
              echo "</title>";
              echo "<link type='text/html' href='http://www.apporan.com/reports/report.php?id=".$row['id']."'/>";
              echo "<id>";
              echo "tag:apporan.com,2015:http://www.apporan.com/reports/report.php?id=".$row['id'];
              echo "</id>";
              echo "<updated>";
              echo $articleDateRfc3339;
              echo "</updated>";
                echo "<author>";
                echo "<name>";
                echo $row['author'];
                echo "</name>";
                echo "</author>"; 
              echo "<summary>";
              echo $row['subtitle'];
              echo "</summary>";

              $i++;
            }           
        ?>
        </entry>
    </feed>
```

Although this is doing the job. I want to parse/embed this to mye page. Can anyone help me?enter code here

Comment: numerous jQuery plugins you can use

Comment: Can you help with some references?

Comment: should be easy to find in google with `jquery feed plugin`. Also fairly easy to do yourself if you are familiar with ajax